# Avoiding MainEvaluate in a CompiledFunction to fetch global variables

Tags: compile, scoping

I'm trying to write a simulation using Mathematica 8.0. Since I will most likely be doing the same operation over and over again, I'm trying to `Compile` whatever I can. However, I've been having problems avoiding `MainEvaluate` calls when I define `CompiledFunction` objects which refer to global variables. A simplified sample of what I'm trying to use is:

```
g = 4.49*^3;
m = 1.;
s = 1.;
ϵ = 2.;
sAcceleration = Compile[{{sPosition, _Real, 1}},
   (-g (m + s))/(sPosition.sPosition + ϵ*ϵ)^(3/2) sPosition];
```

I have also tried wrapping the whole thing inside a `Module`, to no avail:

```
sAcceleration2 =  Compile[{{sPosition, _Real, 1}},
  Module[{gg = g, mm = m,  ss = s, ϵϵ = ϵ^2},
    (-gg (mm + ss))/(sPosition.sPosition + ϵϵ)^(3/2) sPosition]];
```

They seem to run just fine. However, when I take a look at what the `CompiledFunction` is trying to do internally using `CompilePrint`

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint[sAcceleration]
CompilePrint[sAcceleration2]
```

I get, respectively

> 1 R1 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{sPosition}, g][ T(R1)0]]
>
> ...
>
> 3 R1 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{sPosition}, m][ T(R1)0]]
>
> 4 R4 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{sPosition}, s][ T(R1)0]]
>
> ...
>
> 7 R6 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{sPosition}, ϵ][ T(R1)0]]
>
> 8 R7 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{sPosition}, ϵ][ T(R1)0]]
>
> ...

and

> 1 R1 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{sPosition}, g][ T(R1)0]]
>
> 2 R3 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{sPosition}, m][ T(R1)0]]
>
> 3 R4 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{sPosition}, s][ T(R1)0]]
>
> 4 R6 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{sPosition}, ϵ][ T(R1)0]]
>
> ...

Since I will most likely be toying with different values for these variables in different simulation runs, but they will be held constant within a given run, can I avoid both `MainEvaluate` and feeding these variables to my function as additional arguments? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to wait a bit longer before accepting the answer, in case someone else comes up with something better than I did. You can remove the checkmark for a while to encourage others to look at the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
g = 4.49*^3;
m = 1.;
s = 1.;
ϵ = 2.;
With[{g = g, m = m, s = s, ϵ = ϵ},
 sAcceleration = Compile[{{sPosition, _Real, 1}},
     (-g (m + s))/(sPosition.sPosition + ϵ*ϵ)^(3/2) sPosition];
 sAcceleration2 = Compile[{{sPosition, _Real, 1}}, 
   Module[{gg = g, mm = m, ss = s, ϵϵ = ϵ^2},
     (-gg (mm + ss))/(sPosition.sPosition + ϵ)^(3/2) sPosition]];
 ]
```

that is, inject the values before evaluation with `With`.

By the way, if you do `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"CompileReportExternal" -> True}]` then you'll be warned of calls to the main evaluator at compile time (i.e. without using `CompilePrint`).

Comment: Works as intended! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, using capitalized variable names can lead to conflicts. For instance, `N` and `K` are reserved. I use things like `thisIsAVar` to avoid this. Of course nothing will happen to you if you keep using `G` and so on, but you can sometimes end up with hard to diagnose bugs.

Comment: I know, thanks. I usually use longer names for variables, but just this time I gave in to laziness.

Answer (score 7):

You could go even further than @acl's answer with something like this:

```
mkCF[g_, m_, s_, e_] := Module[{body, SPosition},
  body = (-g (m + s))/(SPosition.SPosition + e*e)^(3/2) SPosition;
  With[{body = body}, Compile[{{SPosition, _Real, 1}}, body]]
  ]
```

This has the advantage that body has seen an evaluation which in this cases means a simplification and consequently less to compute.