# Can RecurrenceTable make use of CompiledFunction?

Tags: compile, recursion

I'm trying to implement a discrete-time 2D Verlet algorithm for a point-mass subject to a softened gravitational interaction as a test for a more computationally intensive simulation using `RecurrenceTable` to recursively compute

$$
\vec{x}_{n+1} = 2 \vec{x}_{n} - \vec{x}_{n-1} + \vec{a}_{n}dt^2
$$

Initial conditions are pseudorandomly generated in a rather complicated way that is not really relevant to the issue I'm experiencing, so consider for instance

```
Sinitialposition = Developer`ToPackedArray[{-5.35386, -73.709}];
preSinitialposition = Developer`ToPackedArray[{-5.45406, -73.8311}];
```

Sample values for constants used in the following are

```
dt = 1.*^-3;
G = 4.49*^3;
M = 1.;
S = 1.;
ϵ = 2.;
```

Acceleration is given by the `CompiledFunction` object `SAcceleration`, defined by

```
With[{G = G, M = M, S = S, ϵ2 = ϵ^2},
 SAcceleration = 
   Compile[{{SPosition, _Real, 
      1}}, (-G (M + S))/(SPosition.SPosition + ϵ2)^(3/2) SPosition]];
```

(I [have been suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7630/avoiding-mainevaluate-in-a-compiledfunction-to-fetch-global-variables) this syntax in order to avoid `MainEvaluate` calls while still having the freedom to call for global variables)

When I call

```
RecurrenceTable[{SR[n + 1] == 
   2 SR[n] - SR[n - 1] + dt^2 SAcceleration[SR[n]], 
  SR[0] == Sinitialposition, SR[-1] == preSinitialposition}, SR, {n, 
  1, 1000}]
```

I keep running into a warning which tells me, I think, that Mathematica is using the non-compiled version:

> `CompiledFunction::cfta: "Argument SR[n] at position 1 should be a rank 1 tensor of \!\(\"machine-size real number\"\)s."`

I tried investigating using `Trace`, and the relevant portion of the output (at position `[[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]]`) is:

```
CompiledFunction[{SPosition},-(((4490. 2.) SPosition)/(SPosition.SPosition+4.)^(3/2)),-CompiledCode-][SR[n]]
```

So it seems that `RecurrenceTable` calls the function with the given symbolic arguments. Does this mean I cannot make use of `CompiledFunction` objects or does `RecurrenceTable` auto-compile? Am I going to encounter performance hits because of this? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: If `RecurrenceTable[]` were only `HoldAll`... too bad it isn't, so there you are.

Comment: @OleksandrR. It works. Why don't you state that as an answer? It is precisely what I've been looking for! :O

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason for this message is that the compiled function is called with the symbolic argument `SR[n]` in the definition of the recurrence relation:

```
SAcceleration[SR[n]]
```

> CompiledFunction::cfta: "Argument SR[n] at position 1 should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers."

```
-((8980. SR[n])/(4. + SR[n].SR[n])^(3/2))
```

The recurrence is then evaluated using the symbolic form returned by `SAcceleration`. While I don't think you'll gain much (if anything) in the way of performance by using a compiled function for such a simple expression, if you want to get rid of the message and avoid conversion to the uncompiled form, you can prevent `SAcceleration` from evaluating for symbolic arguments. One way to do this is shown by @Sjoerd, but in version 8 there is another way that's specific to compiled functions, using [`RuntimeOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuntimeOptions.html#555699519) as follows:

```
RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}
```

Adding this we have:

```
With[{G = G, M = M, S = S, ϵ2 = ϵ^2},
 SAcceleration = Compile[{{SPosition, _Real, 1}},
  (-G (M + S))/(SPosition.SPosition + ϵ2)^(3/2) SPosition,
  RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}
 ]
];
```

Now, `SAcceleration[SR[n]]` returns unevaluated and the resulting behaviour is as you intended.

Answer (score 9):

If you could define your compiled function using an intermediate step I think it should work:

```
With[{G = G, M = M, S = S, ϵ2 = ϵ^2}, 
  SAcceleration1 = 
      Compile[{{SPosition, _Real,1}}, 
              (-G (M + S))/(SPosition.SPosition + ϵ2)^(3/2) SPosition]
];

SAcceleration[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := SAcceleration1[{x, y}]
```

Running it:

```
rt = RecurrenceTable[{SR[n + 1] == 2 SR[n] - SR[n - 1] + dt^2 SAcceleration[SR[n]], 
                      SR[0] == Sinitialposition, 
                      SR[-1] == preSinitialposition}, 
                      SR, {n, 1, 1000}
     ];

ListPlot[Norm /@ Differences@Partition[rt, 2, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1. I'm too late, having some chat when editing, LOL

Comment: @Silvia Happens all the time. If I hadn't been editing the question first I'd be quicker too. I'll vote for you as well, as your answer is equally valid.

Comment: It is indeed equipollence. Maybe I delete mine. (if it won't do harm for others~)

Comment: @Silvia The main difference would be that your solution would fail in the unlikely case that someone would enter a list consisting of *symbolic* values.

Comment: Yes, I got lazy for it :D And `NumericQ` would not be enough for preventing a `Complex` list :) Maybe something like `x_?(Element[#, Reals] || Element[#, Integers] &)`

Comment: @Silvia Touché. ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3947/discussion-between-silvia-and-sjoerd-c-de-vries)

Comment: However, on my laptop this solution gives a `Timing` of ~14 s, while the uncompiled version runs for ~2.5 s, making it actually worse, performance-wise! :O